# Can't Download: Could not retrieve data from URL from my wordpress website

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress, facebook-graph-api

I am managing this website www.nayitazi.com. I share most of my posts on my Facebook page with thumbnail created for every post. Everything worked fine until few days before, becuase now when I share post like this URL: http://www.nayitazi.com/current-affairs/geo-news-9pm-bulletin-15th-october-2013/....Facebook just shows the Url with no thumbnail.

I tried the facebook debugger https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=www.nayitazi.com, and it gives me

Can't Download: Could not retrieve data from URL.

I am new to wordpress and doesn't know what's happening exactly, any help towards right direction will be really appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any security based Wordpress plugins installed that would ban IP addresses, or user agents based on activity?

Comment: I have this plugin 'Limit Login Attempts' which may be what you are asking. Is this creating problems?